# Creating raster grid of world with pixel values equaling surface area that grid cell contains?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, area

How do I create a raster grid of the world with pixel values equaling the surface area that the grid cell contains?

For example, if you wanted to create a textbook example of how a projection visually distorts the area at the poles by having pixel values being hectares of land contained by that pixel, how would you do it?

Note that I do not need actual land area in the pixel - I just need the surface area of the featureless surface that the same raster grid could be applied to. I am using raster grid-cells as observations for OLS regressions, and this information will be useful for me to derive other data.

Comment: I might be missing something, but this doesn't seem difficult. Are you asking in a specific software (qgis?) or are you looking for possible griddings? http://test.barrycarter.info/gettile.php is probably not what you're looking for, but I enjoy annoying people with random links to my site.

Comment: I agree that this does not seem conceptually difficult. All colleagues that I have consulted agree, but none of us know how to do this. This isn't data dependent, and it isn't software suite dependent (R, QGIS, ArcGIS, Python, whatever). To clarify my intent with other wording...(1) Create a blank raster in R with resolution A of your choosing, extent of the world, prime meridian C of your choosing, and angular unit D of your choosing. (2) Project the raster into something that will measure distance in meters. (3) Fill all grid-cell values with the area contained in that grid-cell.

Comment: Feel free to contact me directly in google hangouts: carter.barry@gmail.com (I'm around intermittently most days). If you use latitude/longitude "rectangles" for your cells, computing area should be trivial.